# Too much pumpkin purée in pumpkin muffins

Tags: substitutions, pumpkin, puree

I was making the 2 ingredient pumpkin muffins (15 oz can of pumpkin purée and 1 box spice cake mix). I accidentally put in a 29 oz can of pumpkin purée. What can I expect??

Comment: So...what did you get?

Answer (score 1):

That you will need to test for done-ness (and bake longer to get to it) and it will probably be heavy and closer to pie filling than muffin-like, texture-wise. By now I expect you know, having been an hour...perhaps you've invented the pumpkin equivalent of brownies? Orangeies?

Answer (score -2):

the mixture seems great for soft pumpkin  brownies. Add the pumpkin spice and chocolate and bake a little longer.

Comment: Important reminder: we have rather strict rules about self-promotion. In short, you may link to your site under two conditions: a) the answer is primarily focused on answering the questions and still works even without following the link and b) you clearly and explicitly disclose your affiliation, right in the post (in your profile is not sufficient). Read more about this [here.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: With that in mind, linking to a complete different recipe with different ingredients doesn’t answer the asker’s question about fixing a mishap and is as standalone answer very slim at best.